# Minimal Time for Quantum System to Reach Orthogonal State

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hamiltonian, time-evolution

I am trying to determine the minimal time $t$ where a single qubit system (as detailed below) reaches the orthogonal state $|1\rangle$. I have arrived at an answer, but I am not entirely sure whether my logic is correct. There was a suggestion the answer would be in terms of either the expectation value or the standard deviation of the energy...

Consider a single qubit with Hamiltonian
$$
H = E_0|E_0\rangle \langle E_0| + E_1|E_1\rangle \langle E_1|
$$
where the eigenstates are:
$$
|E_0\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle + |1\rangle), \quad |E_1\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle - |1\rangle)
$$
Let $| \psi \rangle$ be a quantum state that starts at $|\psi(0)\rangle = |0\rangle$.
We can write our unitary operator (using $\hbar = 1$) as
$$
U(t) = e^{-itH}
$$
and noting we have
$$
U(t)|E_0\rangle = e^{-itE_0}|E_0\rangle, \quad U(t)|E_1\rangle = e^{-itE_1}|E_1\rangle
$$
We have $\psi(0) = |0\rangle$. Rearranging gives
$$
\sqrt{2}|E_0\rangle = |0\rangle + |1\rangle, \quad \sqrt{2}|E_1\rangle = |0\rangle - |1\rangle
$$
So, we have $\psi(0) = |0\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|E_0\rangle + |E_1\rangle)$, thus time evolution is
$$
|\psi(t)\rangle = U(t)|\psi(0)\rangle = e^{-itE_0}|E_0\rangle + e^{-itE_1}|E_1\rangle
$$
Now, we can write this in terms of the computational basis $|0\rangle, |1\rangle$.
$$
|\psi(t)\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(e^{-itE_0}|E_0\rangle + e^{-itE_1}|E_1\rangle\right)
$$
$$
= \frac{1}{2}\left((e^{-itE_0} + e^{-itE_1})|0\rangle + (e^{-itE_0} - e^{-itE_1})|1\rangle\right)
$$
For $|\psi(t)\rangle$ to be orthogonal to the state $|0\rangle$, we would need the coefficient of the $|0\rangle$ component to be zero i.e. zero amplitude with respect to $|0\rangle$.
For this to occur, we need
$$
\frac{1}{2}(e^{-itE_0} + e^{-itE_1}) = 0
$$
$$
\Rightarrow e^{-itE_0} = - e^{-itE_1}
$$
$$
\Rightarrow \log(e^{-itE_0}) = \log(- e^{-itE_1})
$$
$$
\Rightarrow -itE_0 = \log(-1) - itE_1
$$
$$
\Rightarrow -itE_0 + itE_1 = i\pi
$$
$$
\Rightarrow t = \frac{i\pi}{iE_1 - iE_0} = \frac{\pi}{E_1 - E_0}
$$

I think that this term $E_1-E_0$ may link in with the expectation value of the energy? As it is equally likely to be either $E_1$ or $E_0$. Is anyone able to advise if this seems a correct approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is indeed correct and elegant! To find the minimal time in terms of the expectation value of the energy, you just need to compute:

1. Calculate the expectation value of the energy at time:

$$\langle H \rangle = \langle \psi(t) | H | \psi(t) \rangle.$$

2. Carry out this calculation, which is straightforward, to conclude that:

$$\langle H \rangle = \frac{E_0}{2} + \frac{E_1}{2} = \frac{E_0 + E_1}{2}.$$

3. Now, express the minimal time as a function of the expectation value, and you'll get:

$$t = \frac{\pi}{2(\langle H \rangle - E_0)}.$$

This expression relates the minimal time to the expectation value of the energy. Whether it's more useful or meaningful depends on the specific context of your problem, but it provides an alternative way to express the minimal time.

Comment: Ah! Amazing! Just to check, would it be necessary to prove that this is indeed the minimal time, or is this already the case since we were working with the time evolution?

Comment: @2307 you don't need to prove separately that the expression you derived for the minimal time is indeed the minimal one.  Note that the derivation you've provided is follows directly the time evolution of the state $|0\rangle$, and it correctly gives you the (minimal) time at which the quantum state becomes orthogonal to the initial state.

Answer (score 2):

You have the right steps and final answer, but in reference to your question about showing the time you found to be the minimal time, realise that when you write $\log(-1) = i\pi$, you *are* making the minimal choice, because this is not the only solution. The general solution is of the form $i(2n+1)\pi$, where $n$ is a whole number.

As a side note, you can also rigorously prove why the expectation value of the hamiltonian must be equal to $\frac{E_0 +E_1}{2}$ (i.e, you do not need to use heuristic or logical arguments). Cheers!